# Logging IIS 7 connection failures

Tags: windows, iis

I have a web service application running on Windows Server 2008.

A number of clients are complaining about network connectivity issues and I am trying to diagnose the issues.  My IIS Log files do not have any entries for the majority of the requests that I can identify as having failed.

My suspicion is that these failures due to network connectivity failures closer to the client end, but I'm trying to cover my bases on all ends.

Is there a class of connection failures that would cause a request to be rejected/dropped by IIS/Windows that would cause it to not even be logged by IIS?

Are there any other log information sources that I can dig into to identify failed connections of this kind (low-level TCP connection rejected logs etc?)

The failures that I'm seeing for a given client are intermittent so it is unlikely that they are being blocked by a firewall etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using session state?

Comment: No session state involved per-se.  There is a persistent SessionId cookie (Guid) for each request.

Answer (score 2):

If the request is not being logged by IIS, then any sort of session state won't help (or be affecting this) as that's in the application - one layer above IIS.

The best way to prove this is get your clients to do a telnet to your server on port 80.  If that fails it's not even reaching your server.  They could then do a trace route to see where in the network it's failing.

Comment: Advice is not so helpful with the fact that "the issues are intermittent"